# Set Firefox and Music player on different audio outputs on boot

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, raspberrypi, audio-jack

I have a pie that:

1. runs a server with a web application (that has sound effects)
2. needs to play music

The web application and the musicplayer both need different sound outputs so that they don't get mixed together.

I have a touch-display connected with the pie (hdmi) for my webapplication (Firefox).
And I have an analog jack for the music player connected to the pie.

I there a way I can set the hdmi as audio output for firefox and the analog jack as output for the music player as the pie boots up? This needs to done automatically and can not be done by hand, as the pie will reboot several times a week (at worst).

I can set the correct outputs with PulseAudio but when I reboot the pie I have to manually set it right again, which is not what I want. I guess what I need is a cronjob that does this on boot or something? Or how would I achieve this?